# SQL regular expressions of adjacent characters in a string

Tags: mysql, sql, regex

I'm looking for a way to run a SQL query of a specific pattern in a string by using regular expressions. The string consists of the letter A at the beginning, then 3 random characters, followed by the character pairs "AB", "CD" or "EF". (It cannot be "BA", "DC" ...)

Examples of successful queries:

`AfGhAB`

`AtttCD`

Unsuccessful queries:

`AtreBA`

`AdrtFC`

Thanks,
Orna.

Comment: Which dbms? (Unfortunately regexp are implemented in many product specific ways.)

Comment: The part where you state you want the pattern to match `AB`, then `CD` etc. is not a Regular Expression task tho. It's a common mistake that people want to fix too much with RegEx. I would let the end-part just match freely, and then chop the rest off with code. `^A\w{3}[A-Z]{2}`. You could add an insane row of `OR` rules with RegEx on the last part, but that seems pretty useless and will likely make your query insanely slow as with RegEx searches literally every table-entry has to be inspected.

Comment: You could do something insane like this: `^A.{3}(?:AB|CD|EF|GH|IJ|KL|MN|OP|QR|ST|UV|WX|YZ)$` Good luck with that :P

Comment: Jarlh, I'm using MySql 5.0.50a which is embedded in xampp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way to get what you want, but without using regular expressions:

```
select columns
from tablename
where columnname like 'A%'
  and substring(columnname from 5 for 2) in ('AB','CD','EF')
```

`SUBSTRING` (ANSI SQL) is sometimes called `SUBSTR` etc.

Will probably execute much faster.

Comment: This will likely be a little "faster" than RegEx, but it still results in hitting every table-entry sadly. If you inspect these kind of queries, even with BTREE, the MySQL engine will fail to understand to only go through the `A`-node and skip the rest. It's sad that most SQL engines aren't really smart on these fronts. I like this answer more than a RegEx solution tho :)

Comment: When I wrote this, MySQL wasn't specified.

Comment: At least for MySQL and Postgres I know that the other `AND` statement you added will ignore the `INDEX` `BTREE`. It's really weird why this happens, but it seems to be a flaw where they just made a compromise that 1 LIKE statement will trigger INDEXING, but when adding more complexity it will just drop it's internal optimization for it.

Comment: In the MySQL case, would moving the LIKE to a derived table do any difference? Or do a self JOIN?

Comment: I'm not very sure, would need to test that. I was thinking tho; you might do a `WHERE IN` on a subquery where you only do `WHERE LIKE 'A%'` and use the matched ID's in the `IN` in the parent query to only search in them for the pattern.